# Conditional actions based on error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that watch's a directory for uploads. When it sees a xml file in the directory. The script takes the file and calls a java command line program that using xslt transforms the file.  I want to mv the file to a different directory (errors) if the script or java command line program throws a error during processing. Then email me the error.

I was going to put 
exec 2>  mail -s 'Statement Error Processing'

at the top of the script to catch output for stderr. But that doesn't seem very elegant and doesn't move the file in question.

Answer (score 6):

You can trap error conditions in bash (any statement that returns a non-zero condition that isn't handled inline):

```
trap func ERR
```

Then in func (a function you define) you can do whatever you need to clean up.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
    echo "cleaning up"
}

trap foo ERR

echo "about to execute false"

false

echo "exiting"
```

Running that will result in:

```
./foo.sh
about to execute false
cleaning up
exiting
```

Comment: An `ERR` trap or `set -e` don't really seem beneficial if there is only one command to check ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need two things here. First, determine if the program fails. This is usually known by the return value of the program's `main()` function. If the program returns anything different to 0, there is an error.

In any case, the second thing you have to do is to capture the standard error output to a file to later mail it. So:

```
if ! program inputfile 2> errorfile ; then
    mv inputfile error_directory
    mail -s "error" < errorfile
fi
rm errorfile
```

You have to check, though, if your program follows this convention to signal an error.

Comment: `test` should not be literal here. The program should be invoked directly after the `!` keyword, the `test` builtin utility is not involved.